# keyboard layout differs from my us intl

Tags: 12.04, hp, keyboard-layout

my hp probook has a us intl keyboard with eurosymbol on 5, but left shift key is right next to 'z'. that one is not available in my keyboard list. now my shift and ctrl keys are not working. is this keyboard so odd [question mark]

Answer (score 0):

Go to "System Setting..." > "Keyboard Layout" and from there you will be able to add another layout that fits you keyboard, so just click the "+" button, select the right layout and then you just need to delete the current layout by selecting it and clicking in the "-" button and your problem will be solved.